# Can anyone think of a way to print this pattern without storing data outside of the method?

Tags: java, recursion

This recursive method accepts a non-negative integer (in this case 6) and prints the following pattern based on the integer:

Comment: Pass it as a parameter?

Comment: There must only be one parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

Print the first line, recurse, print the last line.
The recursion pattern here is that the middle part is the same as your function with `a-1`.

```
public static void printPattern(int a){
    if (a != 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        printPattern(a-1);
        for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

So, how do you get this? Look at the output of `printPattern(2)`:

```
**
*
*
**
```

and for `printPattern(3)`

```
***
**
*
*
**
***
```

As you can see, the output of `printPattern(3)` contains the output of `printPattern(2)`.

So our function should only output the part that is not in `printPattern(2)`:

- The `*` `a` times.
- Call `printPattern(a-1)`
- And again the `*` `a` times.

Now, there is just a piece missing: the **abort condition**

When we look at the output for `a = 0`, the function behaves different.
It does not print anything.

And that's our abort condition.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, your exit condition is between the two print instructions.  The requirement is a balanced set of stars; as such on the final recursion there will only be 1 star.  The exit `if (a < 1) return;` should be first?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static void printPattern(int a) {

    if(a > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        printPattern(a-1);
        for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution so that we dont have to guess why your solution works.

Comment: It prints the first line of the inverted triangle. Then every time it prints one * less via the recessive function call until a == 1. After the recessive function call, it prints the triangle. Each time it returns back to the caller, it prints one * more.